# grok pattern to extract multiline SQL from log file

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have recently started dabbling with ELK to process log files. Most of the examples that I have seen are about processing single lines of log but my log file has following structure

```
ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 SELECT statement with ID: AECCAA8
SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */
      T1.CONFLICT_ID,
      T1.LAST_UPD,
      T1.CREATED,
      T1.LAST_UPD_BY,
      T1.CREATED_BY,
      T1.MODIFICATION_NUM,
      T1.ROW_ID,
      T1.NAME,
      T1.BU_ID,
      :1
   FROM 
       SIEBEL.S_RESP T1
   WHERE 
      (T1.ROW_ID = :2)
   ORDER BY
      T1.NAME
ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 
Bind variable 1: ,,,SADMIN,00000002576a1de0:0,,Responsibility,Account Screen Homepage View
ObjMgrSqlLog    Detail  4   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 Bind variable 2: 0-30
ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 User search spec: "0-30"
ObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 User sort spec: NameObjMgrSqlLog    Debug   5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 System sort spec: ObjMgrSqlLog  Debug   5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 ObjMgrSqlCursorLog  Prepare 5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 Begin: PrepareStmt for Sql Cursor at aeccaa8ObjMgrSqlCursorLog  Prepare 5   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 End: PrepareStatement for Sql Cursor at aeccaa8ObjMgrSqlLog Detail  4   00000002576a1de0:0  2016-06-22 12:15:34 
***** SQL Statement Prepare Time for SQL Cursor with ID AECCAA8: 0.000 seconds *****
```

These type of sections are sprinkled throughout the log files. I need to extract the actual SQL statement along with other details such as execution time which is contained in the last line of such section

```
***** SQL Statement Prepare Time for SQL Cursor with ID AECCAA8: 0.000 seconds *****
```

I have been able to extract he initial values such as level, statement id, date using the following grok pattern

```
input {
    file {
        path => "c:/slog/test_log.txt"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{WORD:source}\t%{WORD:type}\t%{NUMBER:level}\t%{HEXID:id}"}
        patterns_dir => ["c:/elasticsearch/pattern_dir"]
    }
    mutate {
    remove_field => ["id"]
  }
}
output {
file {
    path => "c:/slog/test_output.txt"
}
}
```

Here is the detail of the custom patterns used:

```
SDATE (?:(\d\d){1,4}-\d{1,2}-(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])\s(?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?))
HEXID (%{BASE16NUM}:%{NUMBER})
```

I realize that I need to use multiline plugin for the SQL statement but I not able to get my head around on how to start.
Any pointers to multiline pattern that can get me started will be really helpful.

**Update::**
My final goal though is to following tokens out this block

```
statement_id : AECCAA8
SQL SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */
      T1.CONFLICT_ID,
      T1.LAST_UPD,
      T1.CREATED,
      T1.LAST_UPD_BY,
      T1.CREATED_BY,
      T1.MODIFICATION_NUM,
      T1.ROW_ID,
      T1.NAME,
      T1.BU_ID,
      :1
   FROM 
       SIEBEL.S_RESP T1
   WHERE 
      (T1.ROW_ID = :2)
   ORDER BY
      T1.NAME
Bind Variables : [",,,SADMIN,00000002576a1de0:0,,Responsibility,Account Screen Homepage View","0-30"]
sql_time: 0.000
```

**Note**
Formatting of SQL is not important and I understand this will probably wil converted into a single line text

Comment: Please post your complete logstash config. Are you using codec in your input plugin?

Comment: Added the complete config file content. I am trying to use multiline codec as the multiline plugin is deprecated. There is no config for multiline as I am not sure how to start.

Comment: May you please also state what is your expected output?